# How can I change the desktop wallpaper from the command line in Ubuntu Desktop 13.04?

Tags: command-line, 13.04, desktop-background

How can I change the desktop wallpaper from the command line in Ubuntu Desktop 13.04?

I most recent tried the following, but it did not work:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file://$HOME/NaturalHistoryMuseum_EN-US7862662491_1920x1200.jpg
```

*Update*: as commented by @Lucio below, the command worked if I used a path without a variable:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/user/NaturalHistoryMuseum_EN-US7862662491_1920x1200.jpg
```

Comment: The error is that it would not represent the variable as such. So you have to replace `$HOME` with the complete path to your $HOME directory. e.g. `file:///home/USERNAME/NaturalHistoryMuseum_EN-US7862662491_1920x1200.jpg`